# Android- Using /find/{external_id} with TheMovieDB API

Tags: android, imdb, themoviedb-api

So I am building a movie rating app. I am pulling TheMovieDB API and using the "Find" to pull in an array of search results. The API is saying this.

[image]

I need to figure out how to use the IMDB API to get the ID for the movie I want to search for. Any ideas on how to do this? I am trying to read up on the IMDB API but I am getting more confused. A separate but related issue, Android Studio throws this line, W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.themoviedb.org": No address associated with hostname when trying to connect to the API. I had initially thought I could just use the title of a movie I wanted to search in the request call. Could that be what is throwing this error? I made sure I have internet permissions in my manifest.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

IMDB does not provide a public API.  Your best bet is https://www.omdbapi.com/ which is not bad, but does not provide exactly the same results as the IMDB website search.
Another option is to scrape the search results from the Imdb.com website, but that site changes from time to time so you need to update your scraper.
opensubtitles.org api provides an imdb search, slow but good, and you can't overload it or you will be banned.